# Generate a new table using Java/SQL Based on values

Tags: java, sql, database

I am using Java in combination with SQL, as well as Oracle Database to retrieve contents from a spreadsheet I uploaded. If I have a column with the name of each student, and I have a column with their average, and wanted to get the average of the whole class for example, then check if an individual student's average is greater than the class average and put those students who meet those standards on a separate table, how would I go about doing that? I have an idea, but I'm not sure whether this is correct or not. Correct me if I'm wrong.

```
//Select student averages so I can get each student's individual score
resultset = st.executeQuery("SELECT Student_Averages FROM table");
//Get the class average 
stavg = "SELECT Avg(Student_Averages)) AS classAverage FROM table";
rs = st.executeQuery(stavg);
//Iterate through their individual scores and store them in a float variable to 
//compare them later.
while(resultset.next()){
    float studentaverage = resultset.getFloat("Student_Averages");
}   
//Store the class average in a float variable            
float classaverage = stavg.getFloat("Student_Averages"); 
//Compare the individual student average to the class average
if(studentaverage >= classaverage){
//Generate new table with student names
}
```

I am new at working with databases. I am not sure how to generate a new table with the names of those students who meet the requirement. I would appreciate any help!

Comment: I don't see how this would compile. `getFloat` is not a method for the String class, so `stavg.getFloat("Student_Averages");` will fail. 
Does this have to be in JAVA? You could just use SQL.

Comment: It's a ResultSet function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, move this decleration outside the loop

```
while(resultset.next()){
    float studentaverage = resultset.getFloat("Student_Averages");
}
```

Second, since you did

```
stavg = "SELECT Avg(Student_Averages)) AS classAverage FROM table";
```

You should change

```
float classaverage = stavg.getFloat("Student_Averages");
```

To

```
float classaverage = stavg.getFloat("classAverage");
```

Finally to your question: use this to creat the table

```
st.executeUpdate("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tableName (id INT , studentName VARCHAR(SIZE))");
```

Then use this to insert the data to the table

```
String insert = String.format("INSERT INTO tableName("id","studentName") VALUES ('%s','%s)" , idOfStudent someStudentName);

st.execute(intsert);
```